# How to get Google Places API to return results with two or more keywords?

Tags: google-places-api

I am trying to query Google Places API, passing it an origin location and a radius and some keywords. This used to work! Only recently I noticed that the quality of results got a lot worse and from my research it looks like no results are returned if I provide two or more words in the search box.

I prepared a sample HTML file to demonstrate the issue. We are searching around Indianapolis, IN, USA, to see what is wrong type *Indiana* in the search box and click Search. This should return some results. One of them is Indiana State Museum. Let's narrow down the search a bit, type *Indiana State* and we should see the Indiana State Museum in the results list, all right... whoa! Where's it gone? :( Google returns ZERO_RESULTS that way. Am I doing something wrong or did their API change and became almost useless?

Below is my code, you can also [grab the gist](https://gist.github.com/pkrakowiak/4953833) if you like.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&amp;sensor=false"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="search" style="width: 300px;" /><input type="button" id="searchBtn" value="Search"/><br/>
        <div id="map" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;"></div>
        <div id="results" style="width: 600px;height: 600px;background-color:gray;color:white;"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                var indy = new google.maps.LatLng(39.7685825,-86.1579557);

                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    center: indy,
                    zoom: 10
                });

                var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

                $('#searchBtn').click(function() {
                    $('#results').empty();
                    var request = {
                        location: indy,
                        radius: 5000,
                        /*types: ['geocode'],*/
                        name: $('#search').val()
                    };
                    service.nearbySearch(request, function(results, status) {
                        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                            printLocationName($.map(results, function (item) {
                                return {
                                    reference: item.reference,
                                    label: item.formatted_address,
                                    value: item.name,
                                    latitude: item.geometry.location.lat(),
                                    longitude: item.geometry.location.lng()
                                };
                            }));
                        }
                        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
                            $('#results').append('<span>No results.</span><img src="http://i474.photobucket.com/albums/rr104/gio_dim/AVerySadPanda.png"/>')
                        }
                    });
                });

                function printLocationName(places) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < places.length; i++) {
                        $('#results').append('<span>' + places[i].value + '</span><br/>');
                    }
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perhaps related to this [recent 'fix'](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4772)?  Might want to make a note of this there...

Comment: I can confirm using the example in the bug report that 'Optus' returns results, while 'Optus World' will not.  Even though several of the return results for 'Optus' included 'Optus World'.  Very strange...

Comment: Maybe. Thanks for pointing me to that bug report. I actually went and submitted a new bug report right now. http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4933

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's a bug in the API. :(

http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4845

http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4933

Answer (score 0):

the 'name' parameter is used in a very specific search.
Just change 'name' to 'keyword'.